# AbstractUser attributes vs UserProfile Model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a question regarding designing models for the User.
Is it a better approach if you :
create an AbstractUser model and put all extra attributes (eg: phone, mobile, fax) inside the model
**v.s** 
creating a separate model called UserProfile and link it up with the Member using OneToOneField ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user):

> If you’re entirely happy with Django’s User model and you just want to
>   add some additional profile information, you could simply subclass
>   django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser and add your custom profile
>   fields, although we’d recommend a separate model as described in the
>   “Model design considerations” note of Specifying a custom User model.
>   AbstractUser provides the full implementation of the default User as
>   an abstract model.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to store extra information for the user then use a OneToOneField.

But, if you want behavioural changes in your user model, for example, you want the email address or phone number to be used for login, instead of username, or something like that, then inherit from AbstractUser and create a custom user model.

My suggestion is for learning purpose use AbstractUser and AbstractBaseUser whenever you CAN even if u don't need it.