# How to append a database table created by a django model

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I am following the tutorials 
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html
on making a simple user registration website.

The key model defined in model.py is

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

which creates the table *profile* in the database. My question is how do we append this table to include information like user's first/last name and email. I know those information is stored in *auth_user*, but it would nice to have everything on one table.

I am new to django platform. Any explanation or reference is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In order to be able to have a single table for the user, you can use the AbstractUser class. Read this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31377268/977593

Comment: check option 4(Creating a Custom User Model Extending AbstractUser), posted a link in question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to append first_name, last name, and email in Profile model then there is no need of this `user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
so basically you can remove this line
and 
append these field to the model like:

```
first_name = models.TextField(max_length=50, blank=True)
last_name = models.TextField(max_length=50, blank=True)
email = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

and run command: **python manage.py makemigrations** and then
**python manage.py migrate**
But i will not recomend you to do this.

I suggest you to use django auth user model because then you extra fetures of django very easily *like maintaining sessions etc.*
follow :- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/